# How many pairwise nonisomorphic dense subsets exist

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

in the completion of a linear order of cardinality $\kappa$?  Can there be more than $\kappa$?

To be more precise, suppose $L$ is a linear order of cardinality $\kappa$.  Let $\overline L$  denote the completion of $L$.  Can there be more than $\kappa$ different subspaces (suborders) of $\overline L$ which are dense in $\overline L$ and are pairwise nonisomorphic.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It starts in mid-sentence.

Comment: (My previous comment was supposed to hint that titles are *not* part of the question itself. The body of the question is supposed to be self-contained, at least relatively to the title.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think my erroneous comment is easily fixed: $\mathbb R$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ nonisomorphic dense subsets with order types of the form $\eta+\phi_1+\eta+\phi_2+\eta+\phi_3+\cdots$ where $\eta$ is the order type of the rationals and each $\phi_i$ is either the order type of the irrationals or the order type of the reals.

Comment: @bof: That sounds correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in Eric Towers' answer, $\mathbb R$ is the completion of $\mathbb Q$. I will show that there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ nonisomorphic dense subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Let $\mathcal D$ be the set of all dense subsets of $\mathbb R$. It's clear that $|\mathcal D|=2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$; e.g., $\{X:\mathbb Q\subseteq X\subseteq\mathbb R\}\subset\mathcal D$. The relation "is order-isomorphic to" is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal D$; I claim that each equivalence class has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$. (To see this, observe that, if $X,Y\in\mathcal D$ are order-isomorphic, then any order-isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ extends to a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ with itself; and of course there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ such homeomorphisms.) It follows that there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ equivalence classes, i.e., there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ nonisomorphic dense subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Now that's more like it. :)

Comment: So I can't use the upper estimate $\kappa$, or even $2^\kappa$, to help prove my theorem.  I found another way though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So how are there more than $\omega$ pairwise nonisomorphic dense subsets of $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Pick a basis of $\mathbb{Q}$, $B = \{b_i\}$.  Now look at $\{\mathbb{Q} \setminus C \mid C \in \mathcal{P}(B)\}$.  (For motivation, think of the finite complement topology where we've arranged for every pair of surviving open intervals to have distinct lengths.)